# Define a regex to match multiple name variants

Tags: regex

I have for example the following RegEx defined:

```
[\d+]{4}\.[\d+]{3}\.[\d+]{3}\s\s(([\w][.])+\s[\w]+).*

1111.111.111  A.A.A. GEK-HENK                    00    20     01     AFV    2018-06-30 22   TOETS ONDERPANDSWAARDE
```

In the string above, the regex will catch, subgroup 1 the entire string and subgroup 2 it will catch: A.A.A. GEK. It will not catch the indent and the remaining part of the name. This exact same regex needs also catch the following other variants:

The initials are always going fine, its just the last name.

1. HENK (Goes fine)
2. HENK-GEK (Finds only HENK)
3. HENK GEK (Finds only HENK)
4. HENK-GEK YES (Finds only HENK)
5. HENK GEK-YES (Finds only HENK)
6. HENK GEK YES (Finds only HENK)

How can I edit the regex above to also match last names that work with indents or spaces. The next following character after the last name is always a space. I tried to subgroup it by taking `.*\s` after the last `[\w]+` like this `[w\]+.*\s`. In my eyes that would catch everything until the next space, but it wasnt true.

Please help :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself. Solution:

```
[\d+]{4}\.[\d+]{3}\.[\d+]{3}(\s+)(.*)([\d]{2}\s+[\d]{2}\s+[\d]{2}).*
```

And after catching subgroup $2, i edited the output like this to replace the entire string with trim($2). This will catch all situations from 1 till 6. Thanks bye.